# [Network error]: Error: Error writing result to store for query Using Apollo Link State

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using Apollo-link-state to create and update the store for my application. However, I am getting the following error when performing a mutation:

```
[Network error]: Error: Error writing result to store for query:
 query getLocation {
  location @client {
    coords
    __typename
  }
}

Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
```

My default store looks like this:

```
const defaultState = {
   location: {
    __typename: 'Location',
    coords: [36, -87]
  },
};

export default defaultState;
```

The query I am using in my mutation looks like this:

```
export const GET_LOCATION = gql`
  query getLocation{
    location @client{
        coords
    }
  }
`;
```

I'm not seeing what the problem with the query is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing the id for the default location object at the defaultState, just tried like this and worked:

```
export default {
  location: {
    __typename: 'Location',
    id: 0,
    coords: [36, 23],
  },
}
```